# Android social apps: ability to post on behalf of the user?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-3, sync, facebook, social-networking-service

Ever since I purchased my Samsung Galaxy SIII, it has been displaying a notification which when clicked causes an app to be displayed asking me to log in to Facebook and then displaying the following screen, which asks me whether I want to allow my Samsung Galaxy SIII to post to Facebook for me (the app is different from the Facebook app which can be downloaded from facebook, as there is a separate button to install the Facebook app, and the app asking me this question appears in the Android Task Manager under the name SNS (Social Networking Service) with a Facebook icon next to it):

[image] [image] [image]

If I say yes in the last screenshot above, will my device be posting posts to Facebook without my approval with content I have not even seen?

Thank you for clarifying my suspicion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will have giving consent to post "things" to Facebook without seeing or approving them.

I suggest getting a 3rd party app to help. [SystemPanel App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel.r1&hl=en), a full feature task manager, or [App Detective](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zmarties.detective&hl=en), find every detail about an app. The first is a paid app, but there is a free version available.

Between these 2 apps you will be able find the culprit, get all the details about it, what app installed it, who made it, plus all sorts of other info, shut down the app, and to know the package name to uninstall.

Be careful when installing anything from other apps or questionable social websites. Read the fine print and examine permissions. And always make backups.

---

## [SNS Definition](http://m.gsmarena.com/glossary.php3?term=sns)

A social network service or social networking service, most often called SNS, is a medium for establishing social networks of people who share interests and/or activities.

Social networking sites allow users to share ideas, activities, events, and interests within their individual networks. Most social network services are web based and provide means for users to interact in various ways, such as e-mail and instant messaging.

Modern internet-connected always-online phones stake a lot on SNS connectivity and integration with the various services getting more popular than ever.

---

SNS is used for your social site widgets. It allows to post to multiple social sharing apps at once. Anything that you post on one site will be posted to your other sharing site. It can be safely disabled or uninstalled (root) without hindering Facebook or other apps.

The Play Store has several apps that can manage the SNS. I'll leave the choice for you.

Comment: Thank you for your post. The application is called `SNS`. I was able to see it in the stock Task Manager and also in the `Application manager`. It came with my phone. What I don't understand is what would the purpose of an app posting stuff without me seeing or approving it be? How on earth would the app even know what kinds of things I like or would interest my friends on Facebook? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I really don't get involved with social media (sharing everything in your life with everybody in the world), but it mostly has everything to do with analytics (marketing). You should be able to disable it in stock App Manager, but don't uninstall it (might be necessary for main app).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I was still curious about knowing, if I enable this option in the SNS app, what kind of stuff would it post automatically on my behalf? Thanks.

Comment: OK, perhaps the app is asking for permission to post to Facebook, but not without my consent. Basically, it can be used to post to Facebook using an alternative app to the official Facebook app for Android. Anyways, many people seem to think that with FB you share everything with the whole world, but you can actually make various part of your profile private and can also only share with who you want including with only yourself. Anyways, there is a Facebook app and a Facebook Status widget under Android's Apps button but I don't see the SNS app there, not even undet Task Manager. Not sure why.

Comment: Anyways, the System Panel and App Detective apps you mentioned do not show the SNS application either, which means the app probably deleted itself once I gave the app confirmation. It probably just created a Facebook account under Settings -> Accounts on my Android device so that the various menus of accessible from Android Samsung Galaxy SIII stock applications can post when the user wishes to do so without requiring the user to enter the FB password.