# Twitter asking to "Authorize SNS to use your account"?

Tags: twitter

I've installed the latest version of the Twitter client for Android and logged in. To my surprise, the screen displays the message (also shown in the screenshot below), asking me to authorize the SNS (Social Networking Site/Service) to use my account? I don't understand this question. Assuming SNS is used as a synonym for the Twitter service itself, then what is the "account" they are referring to.

Obviously, the Twitter service automatically has access to my Twitter account, so are they talking about my Android account on my Android device, or perhaps the Gmail account corresponding to the email I provided, which I doubt as such account uses a different password. It seems like Twitter is being intentionally vague here.

If someone could kindly explain what the app is asking for in the screenshot I would be happy to know this.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an Android app.

Comment: This question is [the same as your other question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/91599/android-social-apps-ability-to-post-on-behalf-of-the-user) basically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, I figured out what the app is asking. It's asking to create an account in the **Settings > Accounts** section on my Android device. This enables other applications, including stock applications and user-installed applications, to find out that I have a Twitter account and possibly use it to post to Twitter (provided I give consent to such apps to do so).

The following screenshot shows that after clicking the **Allow** button, the details pertaining to the user's Twitter account are stored on the Android device:

[image: screenshot]